# como hacer trigger after insert de varias filas, de una tabla a otra

Tags: sql

ok tengo 2 tablas, hago un insert de 3 elementos a la tabla1 en la
tabla2 solo se inserta 1 de ellos, como hago para que llegen los 3 o mas.

```
alter trigger histInv
on talmacenDetalle after insert
as
declare @codRef int
declare @idbodega int
declare @codbarra varchar(50)

select 
@codRef=entradaAlmacenid,
@codbarra = codbarra
@idbodega=idalmacen
from inserted 
 
insert into HistMovInv 
values (@codRef,@idbodega,@codbarra)
```

Answer (score 0):

si en la tabla1 agregaba 5 campos en la tabla2 con el trigger solo llegaba 1, viendo unos ejemplo logre hacerlo se ingresan todos
aqui les dejo el codigo, pero si alguien sabe el porque no funciono la consulta anterior talve te dejas un comentario.

```
  alter trigger histInv
    on talmacenDetalle after insert
    as
    insert into HistMovInv (codRef,codbarra,idbodega,cantidad)
 select entradaAlmacenid,codbarra,idalmacen,cantidad from inserted
```